# QoS: MAC-Priority for clients behind a repeater

Tags: dd-wrt, wireless-access-point, repeater, qos

I've setup a wireless network using a Linksys-Router (DD-WRT) as an AP and a TP-Link repeater for range extension.

To manage bandwith for specific users, I've setup QoS-Rules on the AP (DD-WRT) using MAC-Priority:
[image: DD-WRT MAC PRIO]

However *the AP shows only the Repeater's MAC* and the MACs of users inside the AP-Range. The *MAC addresses of users behind the Repeater are not listed*:
[image: AP client MACs]

[image: Repeater client MACs]

**The purple MAC is not listed in the AP-Clientlist.** Its related to a device connected via the TP-Link repeater.

---

**Q:** How can I setup MAC-Priority for repeater-clients? Do I simply add the purple MAC in AP-MAC priority list although it's not listed as a client? I want to setup specific priority instead of giving one priority for all clients behind the repeater by adding the repeater's MAC in the MAC priority list in the AP as done now?

---

If there is (only) a (more complicate) way to achieve this task I'd like to know how, but probably leak knowledge like I leak with port forwarding and things of a kind.

---

Related WDS-Settings as seen below. I am unsure if (and how) these settings must be applied to match the question concept (due to leak of network based knowledge)
[image: WDS-Settings]

Comment: Depending on how the repeater works (did you enable 4 address mode?), the AP may only see the MAC address of the repeater for clients behind the repeater, so you'll have to use e.g. static IP addresses instead of MAC addresses.

Comment: Where to find the "4 address mode"-setting?

Comment: Not sure where it is in the GUI, as I don't use DD-WRT. But see https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeating_Mode_Comparisons. "WDS" is 4-address-mode (at least in this context, it can also be the name for a proprietary protocol).

Comment: I am not a professional but found related settings but still confused how and if these settings should be applied and would match the concept. To clearify, I've added an additional screenshot to the question

Comment: What happens if you enter manually the MAC addresses of the users behind the Repeater, even if they are not listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main concepts are required to clear this up for you:

1. Layer 2 Broadcast domain

A "Broadcast Domain" is also known as a LAN segment. Layer 2 communications (MAC Addresses) only propagate within one Broadcast Domain. This is defined by switch or VLAN. To get to another LAN segment you need Layer 3, IP routing. In your case, the repeater routes to the main router and vice versa. Routers are not MAC aware. Thus you will never see MAC addresses from a different segment.

2. QoS Headers

QoS works by attaching a IEEE P802.1p header that describes the priority of the packet. QoS aware devices will keep the header as they pass the packet. Any device that is not QoS aware will strip the header.

For this to work the header must be placed on by the repeater. Then the main router needs to accept and understand the header (it appears to).

You can also configure QoS based on protocol, instead of device.

MORE INFORMATION:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_domain

Comment: Lots of information to dig into. Thank you a thousand times sir, this will help, if not - one might replace either me or the hardware.